# how do i get the value of HiddenField in page_init?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, page-init

I have set `HiddenField` value from `jQuery` and i want to use this `HiddenField` value in `page_init` event, but each time i get blank value. what would be the issue.

```
$('#hfKitchenID').val(kitchenid);

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = hfKitchenID.Value;
}
```

Comment: why not on **PageLoad**??

Comment: i am working with `JSON` to append html so no meaning in PageLoad, and in some cases based on what result i got from JSON i want print pdf using WebClientPrint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370217/asp-net-hidden-field-persistence-during-life-cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the value of the hidden field on `Page_init` because the value of the hidden field is save in `ViewState`, and `ViewState` is not accessible on `Page_Init`.

In the page life cycle the `LoadViewState` Event occurs just after the `Init` Event.

Comment: any other possible solution like, do i store in `Session` and get the result in `Init`?

Comment: Yeah, of course you can store in Session.
Can you please explain what is your scenario exactly, so that I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you that please use Request in Page Init event to get the value of hiddenfield control.

Please check the sample below ,hope it can help you.

1.Code in page(.aspx):

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function SetValueToHidden() {
                var hidden = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
                var text = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
                hidden.value = text.value;
            }
        </script> </head> <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Input text:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ShowText" OnClientClick="SetValueToHidden()" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        </div>
        </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

2.Code in page(.cs):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["HiddenField1"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write(Request["HiddenField1"].ToString());
        }
    }
```